# Cannot call max function on a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to compare sum of first and last element in a list, second to second last, and so on.
The list has even number of numbers.
But when I call the max() function on a list, it gives me an error. Help me

```
li = [12,31,51,72,93,11,132,151,172,144]
sum1 = []

for i in range(len(li)):
    sum1.append(li[i] + li[len(li)-1-i])
print(sum1)
print(max(sum1))
```

and the error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-04d301659610> in <module>
      5     sum1.append(li[i] + li[len(li)-1-i])
      6 print(sum1)
----> 7 print(max(sum1))
      8 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: You must have created a variable called `max` .

Comment: No sir, I have not created any variable as max @DYZ

Comment: Then what do you get when you do `print(max)`?

Comment: This code runs without errors on my machine. I am inclined to agree with DYZ. Is there any more code apart from what you have posted?

Comment: No sir, this much code is only there. @tfpf

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my configurations because in the online compiler it worked fine.

Comment: What happens if you add `del max` to the beginning of the code? That should get rid of the variable, and let the name be looked up in the builtin scope again.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible that you have shadowed the built-function, you can use:

```
print(__builtin__.max(sum1))
```

in this way you will use the `max` function that you want